# How to union basic queryset with a queryset with grouped data?

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to union two django querysets where the first queryset is just basic queryset and the seconds one is the queryset with grouped data. Obviously the second queryset will have less fields and some extra fields.

For example I have ReceivedNotification model and this model have 4 main fields.

```
class ReceivedNotification(models.Model):
    receiver = FK(User)
    initiator = FK(User)
    event = Char(choices)
    created = DateTime()
```

So my goal is to get a queryset of all received notifications for user and some of notifications should be grouped with other of the same event type.

The first queryset will be:

```
q1=ReceivedNotification.objects
.filter(receiver=request.user, event__in=[list of some event types])
```

The second one will be:

```
q2=ReceivedNotification.objects \
.filter(receiver=request.user, event__in=[list of different event types])\
.values('receiver', 'event')\
.annotate(created=Max(F('created')))\
.annotate(grouped_users=ArrayAgg(F('initiator')))
```

These querysets are pretty similar except that q1 doesn't have `grouped_users` column. So i added it:

`q1=q1.annotate(grouped_users=Values('', CharField())`

At this point I am trying to union q1 with q2 but I got an error:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: UNION types character varying[] and integer cannot be matched`

Can it be a problem that q1 is a queryset with objects of ReceivedNotification model and q2 is like queryset with dict data?

Answer (score 0):

from django.db.models import Q

Import Q object to your project.

```
query_one = example.filter()
query_two = example.filter()
new_query = Q(query_one) | Q(query_two)
```

This code will combine your querysets in same variable. Try this.

Comment: Your solution works but I forgot to mention that I need to filter my combined queryset by `created` param.